# How do i connect messageBox when it is clicked, to a slot?

Tags: qt

I want to create a messagebox asking question whether a user want to play again or not. When user clicks either a button , it performs a task. The task is defined in a slot. How can i connect the button click to that slot??

```
QMessageBox::StandardButton reply=QMessageBox::question(this,"GAME Over-Do you want to play again?");
connect(QMessageBox,SIGNAL(buttonClicked()),this,SLOT(box());
```

it shows `QMessageBox` is a class, and is unable to connect it to that slot. I want to connect to that slot.

Comment: Why do you want to connect that button click to a slot? As soon as the user presses yes or no, you have to check the result and act accordingly like:

        if(reply==QMessageBox::StandardButton::Yes) {
                QMessageBox::information(this, "Ok", "You have answered YES");
                box();
        } else {
                QMessageBox::information(this, "Title", "You have answered NO");
        }

Answer (score 2):

There is different ways to use [QMessageBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html). You could use [blocking static functions](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#static-public-members) of [QMessageBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html) and check response like that:

```
QMessageBox::StandardButton reply = QMessageBox::question(this,"Title", "GAME Over-Do you want to play again?");
if(reply == QMessageBox::Yes)
{
    //call your slot
    //box();
    qDebug() << " Yes clicked";
}
else
{
    //Game over
    qDebug() << "game over";
}
```

but this will block execution of your code until user clicks some button in  message box.

If you need your code run forward without waiting for user response you could use QMessageBox in non-blocking way:

```
QMessageBox * msg = new QMessageBox(QMessageBox::Question, "Title", "GAME Over-Do you want to play again?", QMessageBox::Yes| QMessageBox::No, this);
connect(msg,SIGNAL(accepted()),this,SLOT(box()));
connect(msg,SIGNAL(rejected()),this,SLOT(gameover()));
msg->show();
qDebug() << "Not blocked";
```